# How to align items inside container-fluid keeping full-width on resize to match a container on bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want a full-width container with pictures that can be scrolled, then I have other content on my website that is inside a container...

My question is:
Is there any way to set a padding-left on my item inside container-fluid that match the content that is outside, (inside a container) when you resize the website?

I mean always be aligned the padding and the container

example:

[image]

here is my code atm:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title></title>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>
 <body>
  <style type="text/css">
   .container {
    max-width: 1450px;
    background: lightblue;
   }
   .container-fluid {
    background-color: wheat;
   }
   ul {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
   }
      li {
    list-style: none;
       float: left;
      }
     </style>

  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
     <h1>Carousel Header</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid px-0">
   <ul>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/229/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/230/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/231/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/232/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/233/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/234/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/235/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/236/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/238/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/239/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/240/200/300.jpg"></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
     <h2>TEXT</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
     <p>some text</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why use a separate container fluid?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title></title>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>
 <body>
  <style type="text/css">
   .container {
    max-width: 1450px;
    background: lightblue;
   }
   .container-fluid {
    background-color: wheat;
   }
   ul {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
   }
      li {
    list-style: none;
       float: left;
      }
     </style>

  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
     <h1>Carousel Header</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">
   <ul>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/229/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/230/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/231/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/232/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/233/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/234/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/235/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/236/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/238/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/239/200/300.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/240/200/300.jpg"></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
     <h2>TEXT</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
     <p>some text</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Use this code hope its you want like this .